# kivy using markup for two different text sizes in a single button not working

Tags: text, size, kivy

I'm in the process of converting an application from pure Python, to using kivy for screen handling.  I'm a kivy newbie!

I'm attempting to replicate a screen which displays current date and time, on two lines, with different sizes for the two lines.  I use two different [size=?] markups in the string to be displayed, but the two lines are always displayed at the same size (the second size specified) - how can I get them to be different sizes?

I have seen suggestions that this could be achieved using html, but fear that would be horribly inefficient.

Code is:

```
<C>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:
                '[size=48]' + app.date + '[/size]' + \
                '\n[size=96]' + app.time + '[/size]'
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            halign: 'center'
            markup: True
            on_press: app.stop()
    Status:
        id: stat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I used your code and the lines had a different font size. Therefore the problem must be outside of the code you provided.

py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


class MyApp(App):
    date = StringProperty('2017-09-30')
    time = StringProperty('Now')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kv:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:
                '[size=48]' + app.date + '[/size]' + \
                '\n[size=200]' + app.time + '[/size]'
            background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
            halign: 'center'
            markup: True
            on_press: app.stop()
```

Alternatively, you can use the following kv-file:

```
Button:
    on_press: app.stop()
    BoxLayout:
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size: self.parent.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label: 
            text: app.date
            font_size: 48
        Label: 
            text: app.time
            font_size: 96
```

To generate sth which also behaves more like a button in kv, changes the background on press.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for trying that - it's much appreciated.  I modified my .py to almost resemble yours (adding the def build(self):), and yes, it works.  I'll have to mess some more.  Obviously, I need to do a little more in the .py - updating the date and time strings on a Clock.schedule_interval.